# Perl RE global matching is not working /.*(11).*/g

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file containing this single line:

`111112111122113`

I want to match all  two element sequences of 1  in all occurrences.

But when I try this
`$ perl -lne 'print $1 if /.*(11).*/g' u`
I get only one result despite the presence of `g` at the end of my RE:

11

[image]
How do I print them all, what's wrong with my RExp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the non greedy quantifier:

```perl
perl -lne 'print $1 if /.*?(11)/g'
#                 here ___^
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/J7uJWJ/1)

But I think you'd better use a loop:

```perl
print $1 while ($inputline =~ /.*?(11)/g)
```

Comment: `$ perl -lne 'print $1 if /.*?(11)/g' u` still gives this one result
11

Comment: @user1642683: `perl -ane 'print $1 while (/.*?(11)/g)' inputfile`